# android how to manage fragments in navigation bar without data lose

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigationbar, fragment-backstack

I have a store app
In this application, the fragments each take their own data from the server and are managed by navigation bar.
I want to receive data any fragment one only once , and will only maintain its last state some time later.
I used the replace , hide functions, but I did not get good results
Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
nav_partition.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment lastFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_layout);
            if (lastFragment instanceof FragmentPartition)
                return;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.hide(lastFragment);
            if (fragmentPartition == null)
                fragmentPartition = new FragmentPartition();
            G.log_toast("is added : " + fragmentPartition);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragmentPartition);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use add instead of replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use savedinstancestate bundle for saving your data. and it can be reused on resuming. Try bellow code.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("bln", true);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("it", 1);
    savedInstanceState.putString("str", "Hello");
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    boolean bln = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("bln");
    int in = savedInstanceState.getInt("it");
    String str = savedInstanceState.getString("str");

}
```

Comment: نه حاجی اشتباه زدی !
چرا قیمه هارو میریزی تو ماستا ؟؟

Comment: pls ask in english

Comment: AFLAH ALI ! tnx for answer and your time :) !